# What is wrong with the code to apply in a list of data frames in R?

Tags: r, list, function

I have a list of the data frame there is something wrong because the code doesn't work for the rest of the list. In a few data frames that have just one column values (column 5 in data frames) the code doesn't calculate the percentage and total. These are the codes that I ran for the list

```
MyFunc <- function(DatFrame) {
  reshape2::dcast(data = DatFrame, formula = PROVINCE + DISTRICT + SUB_DISTRI + VILLAGE ~ ETHNICITY + NMSUKU,
                  value.var = "WEIGHT", fun.aggregate = sum)
}

#run the function on your list.

DCAST_out <- lapply(X = list_lang, FUN = MyFunc)




# to add the total and percentage you have to create the function and run it.

lang_list <- lapply(DCAST_out, function(x){
 
  last_row <- nrow(x)
  total <- sapply(x[, -(1:4)], sum)
  pct <- total / sum(total)
 

  x[last_row+2, ] <- c(rep("Percentage", 4), pct)
  x[last_row+1, ] <- c(rep("Total", 4), total)
 
  x
 
})
```

You can see the problem in the percentage and total row column 5. Those data frames have just values in column 5.

```
structure(list(PROVINCE = c("Percentage", "Total", "53", "53", 
"53", "53", "53", "53"), DISTRICT = c("Percentage", "Total", 
"8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8"), SUB_DISTRI = c("Percentage", "Total", 
"40", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40"), VILLAGE = c("Percentage", 
"Total", "1", "2", "5", "14", "15", "16"), `170_Lamahot/ Lamholot/ Lamkolot` = c(0.100404012114976, 
165.759994506832, 165.759994506832, 288.289995193478, 474.779998779293, 
291.49999141693, 10, 420.60000801087)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Otherwise, for the rest of them, the code runs well and you look at this one, the calculation of percentage and total are correct.

```
structure(list(PROVINCE = c("Percentage", "Total", "94", "94", 
"94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", 
"94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", 
"94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", 
"94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", 
"94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", 
"94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", 
"94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", 
"94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94", 
"94", "94", "94", "94", "94", "94"), DISTRICT = c("Percentage", 
"Total", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "20", "20"), 
    SUB_DISTRI = c("Percentage", "Total", "20", "20", "25", "25", 
    "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", 
    "30", "30", "30", "31", "31", "31", "31", "31", "31", "31", 
    "31", "31", "31", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", 
    "32", "32", "32", "32", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", 
    "33", "33", "33", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", 
    "34", "34", "34", "34", "35", "35", "35", "35", "35", "35", 
    "35", "36", "36", "36", "36", "36", "36", "36", "41", "41", 
    "41", "41", "41", "42", "42", "42", "42", "42", "42", "42", 
    "42", "42", "42", "42", "42", "43", "43", "43", "43", "43", 
    "40", "40"), VILLAGE = c("Percentage", "Total", "2", "5", 
    "1", "6", "1", "6", "7", "8", "13", "14", "15", "20", "21", 
    "22", "23", "29", "30", "2", "4", "5", "6", "7", "13", "14", 
    "16", "17", "18", "2", "7", "8", "10", "16", "17", "18", 
    "19", "21", "22", "24", "3", "4", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
    "13", "14", "15", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "2", "3", "7", "8", "9", "1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
    "1", "7", "8", "10", "11", "2", "11"), `1110_Ketengban` = c(0.977412699880646, 
    18542.7699832916, 63, 0, 0, 90, 317.740001678466, 160, 434.25, 
    297.000002861022, 140, 140, 180, 180, 140, 77, 110, 130, 
    140, 196.269998550414, 680, 243.109992980952, 291.30000114441, 
    275.399994850155, 181.979993820186, 575.25, 258.120011329651, 
    317.440002441405, 130.520000457764, 37.3199996948244, 125.710000991821, 
    283.5, 381.260002136232, 110, 300, 227.240002632141, 233.20000839234, 
    110, 150, 354.620010375984, 299.659999847412, 252.589999198913, 
    315, 159, 259.750007629395, 298.5, 205.79999923706, 247.25000858307, 
    246.49999141693, 231, 232.5, 249.59999084472, 96.030000686646, 
    140, 153.600006103515, 80, 56, 50, 132, 140, 270, 358.719984054565, 
    240, 250, 193.199995994567, 207.9999923706, 175.5, 149.380001068116, 
    96.030000686646, 96.25, 285.939990043639, 183.999996185302, 
    222, 96, 124.79999542236, 150.080001831054, 156.800003051758, 
    51, 93.5, 122.040000915528, 230.5, 265, 418.290006637573, 
    263.159996986386, 295.360000610352, 213.890001296996, 69.3600006103512, 
    210.539993286132, 117.370000839234, 106.70000076294, 178.599992752076, 
    176, 56, 190, 182.75, 140, 0, 0), `1009_Awye/ Awyi` = c(0.0143169039357813, 
    271.609992980952, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.6700000762939, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 232.539993286128, 20.39999961853
    ), `1125_Kupel/ Kupol` = c(0.00617248817539898, 117.100001335144, 
    0, 0, 97.1000013351443, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1266_Una` = c(0.00105422512468349, 20, 
    0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), `1188_Ngalum` = c(0.00104368288349053, 19.8000001907349, 
    0, 0, 9.8000001907349, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -98L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Note: the data frames that have many columns of value the calculation is good. But, the data frames that have values just in column 5 the calculation of percentage and total are wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have only 5 column dataframe and you drop 1st 4 columns with `-(1:4)` you are left with only 1 column and R drops it's dimension and make it a vector which disturbs the calculation.

You can keep the dimension of the dataframe by using `drop = FALSE` while subsetting. This will not change anything for dataframes with more than 5 columns but will keep the dimensions of dataframe which has only 5 columns.

```
lang_list <- lapply(DCAST_out, function(x){
  
  last_row <- nrow(x)
  total <- sapply(x[, -(1:4), drop = FALSE], sum)
  pct <- total / sum(total)
  
  x[last_row+2, ] <- c(rep("Percentage", 4), pct)
  x[last_row+1, ] <- c(rep("Total", 4), total)
  x
})
```